# Erro ao conectar no banco de dados

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados

Tento fazer a conexão no meu bd, mas fica dando o erro "Falha ao conectar!"

Os dados que estão no meu bd sao:

Base de Dados: teste
Tabela: clientes

to tentando conectar por PHP

```
    <?php


$conn = @mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "teste") or die("Falha ao conectar!");

?>
```

e a validação:

```
<?php


require_once "conexao.php";

$email = $_GET['idemail'];
$cpf = $_GET['cpf'];
$query = "SELECT * FROM clientes WHERE cpf = '$cpf' AND email = '$email'";
$querySelect = mysqli_query($conn,$query);

if(mysqli_num_rows($querySelect) <=0){
    echo"<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Email ou cpf incorretos');window.location.href='index.html';</script>";
    die();
}else{
    setcookie("login", $cpf);
    header("Location:Postagem.html");
}
```

Mas sempre que coloco os dados corretos ou incorretos que estão no meu bd, da o mesmo erro de "Falha ao conectar!"

Comment: cheque se você realmente tem um banco com uma database teste, usuário root e senha vazia. ou mude sua mensagem de erro para escrever qual erro que deu, e não apenas que falhou

Comment: Eu mudei a mensagem de erro e quando vou testar, dá a mesma mensagem anterior

Comment: o problema esta no arquivo da conexao, retire o '@', ele está suprimindo os erros. mude para or die("Falha ao conectar!".mysqli_connect_error());

Comment: continua dando o mesmo erro

Comment: mas e a informação adicional? nada? nenhuma mensagem a mais? se você retirou o @ e colocou o mysqli_connect_error() no log, e ainda assim nao mudou nada, devo perguntar, você salvou o arquivo?

Comment: Né pra mudar pra : $conn = ("localhost", "root", "", "teste") or die("Falha ao conectar!".mysqli_connect_error());
e nao mudou nada, e eu salvei

Answer (score 1, accepted):

se essa mudança trazer uma mensagem de erro, edito a resposta para lhe ajudar a corrigir:

```
// cria conexao
$conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "teste");
// exibe motivo da falha, caso haja alguma
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Falha ao conectar!, Motivo: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
```